# Hadoop Map Reduce: Algorithms

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Can someone point me to a good web site with good collection of Hadoop algorithms. For example, the most complex thing that I can do with Hadoop right now is Page Rank. Other than that, I can do trivial things like word counting and stuff.

I want to see a web site that show me other usage of hadoop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's quite a few [machine learning algorithms](http://mahout.apache.org/).  [Here's academic papers](http://atbrox.com/2009/10/01/mapreduce-and-hadoop-academic-papers/) that might be interesting.  Finally here's a [book on map](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~jimmylin/book.html) reduce that looks interesting.

Comment: thanks ! didn't know about mahout. will definitely look this up for my machine learning class =D

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this overview:
http://atbrox.com/2010/05/08/mapreduce-hadoop-algorithms-in-academic-papers-may-2010-update/

Answer (score 1):

This page gives a nice overview of some common Map Reduce patterns in a broad range of applications from creating an inverted index, to implementing Page Rank and doing joins and other set operations

http://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/02/01/mapreduce-patterns/

Basically wherever you see linear algebra (matrix/vector operations) you can apply Map Reduce. This means there are many applications in collaborative filtering (think Netflix recommendations), clustering, and other machine learning algorithms. Another very interesting project to look into is Mahout, which aims at implementing scalable machine learning algorithms, to a large extend on MapReduce through Hadoop.

http://mahout.apache.org/